# Firebase support on Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, mbaas

I have been evaluating Firebase Mobile backend as service features, I doubt on a authentication support of it. Does Firebase MBaaS support "LTPA" authentication? I could see it supports oAuth anyway.

Could anyone tried Firebase help me with your answers and reference on LTPA authentication support by Firebase?

Thanks and Appreciate your suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication supports email + password, Google, Facebook, Github, Twitter and anonymous sign-in out of the box.

On top of that it allows you to integrate any other authentication by [minting a custom token on a server you control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk) and then [using that token on the client to sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients).

There is no built-in support for [IBM LTPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lightweight_Third-Party_Authentication).